# Is there any way I could avoid using the array in PROGMEM in Arduino or modify it?

Tags: c, arrays, arduino

I am using the SSD1306 OLED with Arduino. I am trying to send the Bitmap data via HC-05 Bluetooth module, so I can display the Bitmap image on the OLED.

**The problem I'm facing is :**

```
const uint8_t frame1[] PROGMEM = {
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff,...}
```

The above frame1[] array of preexisting Bitmap is of **const** type and gets stored in **PROGMEM** (has to be of const type) , and thus the array cannot be modified. Is there any other way I could display the received data or even, modify the frame1[] array to display the bitmap instantly as I get the bitmap data over Bluetooth?

**PS : I'm using the U8g library for display**

Comment: It cannot be modified because it is `const`.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

`uint8_t frame1[] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff,...};`

You don't need to save the array in your arduinos **PROGMEM**,
you can also save it as a regular array.

That may only be a problem if your arduinos ram is too low,
so that the frame can only fit into **PROGMEM** - just try it

Comment: You'd still have reload the bitmap (in the array) to your display, but that is a minor problem

Comment: Yes, but the function which has the array as the input parameter needs it to be in PROGMEM.

Comment: Im using Arduino Mega. The bitmap array is of size 1024

Comment: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-GFX-Library/blob/master/Adafruit_GFX.cpp#L773
It does not need to be in PROGMEM

Comment: @Stefan, the Adafruit library is not displaying the bitmap correctly, so I used the U8G library